# Converting Timestamps

Tags: timestamp, python-2.7

I am new to python. I need to convert the timestamp `2012-06-15T05:31:55Z` in to seconds.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get a unix timestamp (i.e., seconds since the Epoch) from that string right?

Then Basically, it's like this:

```
timeStr = "2012-06-15T05:31:55Z"
timestamp = time.mktime( time.strptime( timeStr, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" ) )

print timestamp

>>> 1339756315.0
```

You do need to watch out for time zone info, however.  This code converts to *local time*. You might also want to convert to GMT or something else.